# Yahoo toolbar and local sites (e.g. Intranet)

Tags: internet, windows-explorer, redirection

We have local sites running on IIS in regular MS Windows network.  User base has IE, FireFox and Chrome.  Local sites are isolated by host headers and DNS record created for the common IP accordingly.  This is a regular set-up.

Users without Yahoo Toolbar type http://intranet and the sites resolves.  Users with Yahoo toolbar type http://intranet and the toolbar goes off to search for this site in public domain.  This is irrespective to whether the address is typed into the browser address bar or the toolbar.  All versions of toolbar and IE are affected.

I cannot see a setting on the toolbar to switch this "irritating" behaviour off and simply un-installing the toolbar is not an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote just because "uninstalling the toolbar is not an option."  The Yahoo toolbar was worse than any "malware" I had ever seen.

Comment: @MT: Apologies,  I cannot move this as "we're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users can only post a maximum of one hyperlink. Earn 10 reputation to post more hyperlinks."

Comment: @AS - I understand but user base is dependent - large expatriate community in work force etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only works on FF, but [NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/11787/)?